# Adding the results of multiple SQL selects?

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I have three SQL selects, the results of which I need to add together.  Two of the three use fairly complex joins.

```
select sum(field_one) from t_a join t_b on (t_a.bid = t_b.id) where t_b.user_id=:id
select sum(field_two) from t_c join t_d on (t_c.did = t_d.id) where t_d.user_id=:id
select sum(field_three) from t_e where t_e.user_id=:id
```

What I need is the sum of all three values.  `sum(field_one)+sum(field_two)+sum(field_three)`.  Is there anyway to do this in a single statement?

Comment: try using this
select( (select 15) + (select 10) + (select 20)) logic check my answer below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could `UNION ALL` them.
Do not use `UNION`, since it omits duplicate values (`5+5+5` would result in `5`).

```
Select Sum(s)
From
(
  Select Sum(field_one) As s ...
  Union All
  Select Sum(field_two) ...
  Union All
  Select Sum(field_three) ...
) x
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this without using Union like this

Sample Query

```
select( (select 15) + (select 10) + (select 20))
```

---

Your Query

```
select
(
    (select sum(field_one) from t_a join t_b on (t_a.bid = t_b.id) where t_b.user_id=:id) +
    (select sum(field_two) from t_c join t_d on (t_c.did = t_d.id) where t_d.user_id=:id) +
    (select sum(field_three) from t_e where t_e.user_id=:id) 
)
```

Comment: `+1`: Should work for MySQL and SQL-Server, not Oracle though, but that was not the question :)

Comment: I dont know oracle anyways neither do i know MySQL :P May be i must try to learn it in near future

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `UNION` and a subselect to do that:

```
select sum(`sum`) FROM
(
  select sum(field_one) as `sum` from t_a join t_b on (t_a.bid = t_b.id) where t_b.user_id=:id
  UNION ALL
  select sum(field_two) from t_c join t_d on (t_c.did = t_d.id) where t_d.user_id=:id
  UNION ALL
  select sum(field_three) from t_e where t_e.user_id=:id
) as x;
```

Edit: Updated my answer to use UNION ALL, as suggested by Peter Lang.